# Finding a holomorphic question in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let u : $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ be a function given by $$u(x,y)=xy\;\;\;(x,y\in\,\Bbb R).$$ Find a function v:$\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that u+iv is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$.

This is what I have so far:

Let u=xy. Then $\partial$u/$\partial$x=y and $\partial$u/$\partial$y=x. From the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have $$\partial u/\partial x = \partial v/\partial x=y\;\Rightarrow v=\int y\, dy + h(x)\Rightarrow v={y^2}/2+h(x)$$Also, $$-\partial u/\partial y=\partial v/\partial x=-x\Rightarrow v=\int -x \,dx\Rightarrow v={-x^2}/2+C.$$
I'm stuck beyond this point. I am not sure if my method is correct, but this was the simplest way I could think of answering. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think you mean $\partial /\partial x= \partial v/ \partial y$ in your top line.

Answer (score 0):

One way of noticing that your answer is correct is to see that  for the analytic function $f(z)=z^2 =u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ , with $$u(x,y)=x^2-y^2 ; v(x,y)=2xy $$. In your case, the Real- and Imaginary- parts are reversed with those of $z^2$, and there is a scaling by 1/2. Now, just reverse the Real- and Imaginary- parts by multiplying by (the Complex constant) $2i $ , and you still have a holomorphic (entire, actually) function.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You reached the step

$$ v={y^2}/2+h(x) \longrightarrow (*) $$

Now you need to determine the function $h(x)$. Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives

$$ v_x = h'(x) .$$

Noting that $ v_x=-u_y = -x $ then we have

$$ h'(x)= -x \implies h(x) = -x^2/2 .$$

Substituting back in $(*)$ gives $v(x,y)$

$$  v={y^2}/2-x^2/2 .$$